# Group by / Order by problems MSSQL

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-order-by

Ive been working on a project for a company this summer , still very much a noob even tho im about to graduate school, I keep running into problems dealing with the group by and order by clauses.

Nothing i try seems to be working , heres what i have so far (the syntax is suuuuper messed up for group by / order by )

```
SELECT DISTINCT ACT.ROW_ID , ACT.CREATED , MEM.FIRST_NAME , MEM.LAST_NAME , LOC.NAME , COUNT(*) as "number" , CAT.NAME , SER.NAME , EMP.FIRST_NAME , EMP.LAST_NAME , SER.DURATION , ACT.CASH , COS.NAME , ACT.COMMENTS , ACT.TIP FROM
S_ACTIVITY ACT, S_LOCATION LOC, S_CATEGORY CAT, S_EMPLOYEE EMP, S_SERVICE SER, S_COST_CODE COS, S_MEMBER MEM 
WHERE ACT.EMPLOYEE_ID = EMP.ROW_ID AND ACT.SERVICE_ID = SER.ROW_ID AND ACT.CATEGORY_ID = CAT.ROW_ID AND ACT.COST_CODE_ID = COS.ROW_ID AND
ACT.LOCATION_ID = LOC.ROW_ID AND ACT.MEMBER_ID = MEM.ROW_ID 
GROUP BY LOC.NAME
ORDER BY number
```

Thats with the count as other guides online were saying i needed some sort or count for the ordering ... Heres the original ...

```
SELECT DISTINCT ACT.ROW_ID , ACT.CREATED , MEM.FIRST_NAME , MEM.LAST_NAME , LOC.NAME , CAT.NAME , SER.NAME , EMP.FIRST_NAME , EMP.LAST_NAME , SER.DURATION , ACT.CASH , COS.NAME , ACT.COMMENTS , ACT.TIP FROM
S_ACTIVITY ACT, S_LOCATION LOC, S_CATEGORY CAT, S_EMPLOYEE EMP, S_SERVICE SER, S_COST_CODE COS, S_MEMBER MEM 
WHERE ACT.EMPLOYEE_ID = EMP.ROW_ID AND ACT.SERVICE_ID = SER.ROW_ID AND ACT.CATEGORY_ID = CAT.ROW_ID AND ACT.COST_CODE_ID = COS.ROW_ID AND
ACT.LOCATION_ID = LOC.ROW_ID AND ACT.MEMBER_ID = MEM.ROW_ID 
GROUP BY LOC.NAME
ORDER BY LOC.NAME
```

Thanks for the help , much appreciated ! :)

Comment: (1) I removed the extraneous database tags.  Feel free to add back the tag for the database you are really using.  (2) Learn to use explicit, proper `JOIN` syntax.  Commas in the `FROM` clause are hard to read.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend to read this: [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Comment: There is nothing apparent wrong with the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses of those queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Explicit Joins** - Use them, they are great.  Here is an example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ACT.ROW_ID , ACT.CREATED , MEM.FIRST_NAME , MEM.LAST_NAME , LOC.NAME , CAT.NAME , SER.NAME , EMP.FIRST_NAME , EMP.LAST_NAME , SER.DURATION , ACT.CASH , COS.NAME , ACT.COMMENTS , ACT.TIP FROM
S_ACTIVITY ACT, S_LOCATION LOC, S_CATEGORY CAT, S_EMPLOYEE EMP, S_SERVICE SER, S_COST_CODE COS, S_MEMBER MEM 
WHERE ACT.EMPLOYEE_ID = EMP.ROW_ID AND ACT.SERVICE_ID = SER.ROW_ID AND ACT.CATEGORY_ID = CAT.ROW_ID AND ACT.COST_CODE_ID = COS.ROW_ID AND
ACT.LOCATION_ID = LOC.ROW_ID AND ACT.MEMBER_ID = MEM.ROW_ID
```

Becomes

```
SELECT DISTINCT ACT.ROW_ID, ACT.CREATED, MEM.FIRST_NAME, MEM.LAST_NAME, LOC.NAME, 
                CAT.NAME, SER.NAME, EMP.FIRST_NAME, EMP.LAST_NAME, SER.DURATION, 
                ACT.CASH, COS.NAME, ACT.COMMENTS, ACT.TIP 
FROM        S_ACTIVITY ACT  
INNER JOIN  S_LOCATION LOC  ON ACT.LOCATION_ID = LOC.ROW_ID
INNER JOIN  S_CATEGORY CAT  ON ACT.CATEGORY_ID = CAT.ROW_ID
INNER JOIN  S_EMPLOYEE EMP  ON ACT.EMPLOYEE_ID = EMP.ROW_ID
INNER JOIN  S_SERVICE SER   ON ACT.SERVICE_ID = SER.ROW_ID
INNER JOIN  S_COST_CODE COS ON ACT.COST_CODE_ID = COS.ROW_ID
INNER JOIN  S_MEMBER MEM    ON ACT.MEMBER_ID = MEM.ROW_ID
```

**Distinct** - Distinct is a `SELECT` modifier.  It limits results to distinct rows, and is the same as using `GROUP BY all_columns_here`.  If that's your goal, then remove your `GROUP BY` entirely and you're good to go (see above query).  Which leads to a last point...

**Group By/Order By** - You can use either a `GROUP BY` or an `ORDER BY`, or both. These don't require each other.  In addition, `GROUP BY` is only required by SQL if you have an aggregate, and `ORDER BY` is only required for specific functions.  Otherwise you can use them at will to meet your project requirements.

Comment: Thanks for your help , still got a little tweaking with what to order by , but i think i got some of the logic down, thanks all for comments!

Answer (score 0):

Here is something to get you started since you are new to SO. Welcome, BTW.

I really would read Gordon and Maciej's comments, and the follow on article on JOINS. Good luck with your studies.

This is just to be syntactically correct for MSSQL, with some assumptions on your JOINs. It's not necessarily the results you are looking for.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    ACT.ROW_ID, 
    ACT.CREATED, 
    MEM.FIRST_NAME, 
    MEM.LAST_NAME, 
    LOC.NAME,
    COUNT(*) as "number",
    CAT.NAME,
    SER.NAME,
    EMP.FIRST_NAME,
    EMP.LAST_NAME, 
    SER.DURATION,
    ACT.CASH,
    COS.NAME,
    ACT.COMMENTS,
    ACT.TIP 
FROM
    S_ACTIVITY ACT
    INNER JOIN S_LOCATION LOC on ACT.LOCATION_ID = LOC.ROW_ID
    INNER JOIN LOC. S_CATEGORY CAT ON ACT.CATEGORY_ID = CAT.ROW_ID 
    INNER JOIN S_EMPLOYEE EMP ON ACT.EMPLOYEE_ID = EMP.ROW_ID
    INNER JOIN S_SERVICE SER ON ACT.SERVICE_ID = SER.ROW_ID
    INNER JOIN S_COST_CODE COS ON ACT.COST_CODE_ID = COS.ROW_ID
    INNER JOIN S_MEMBER MEM ON ACT.MEMBER_ID = MEM.ROW_ID 
GROUP BY
    --every column that isn't an aggreggate... i.e. everything except COUNT(*). 
    ACT.ROW_ID, 
    ACT.CREATED, 
    MEM.FIRST_NAME, 
    MEM.LAST_NAME, 
    LOC.NAME,
    CAT.NAME,
    SER.NAME,
    EMP.FIRST_NAME,
    EMP.LAST_NAME, 
    SER.DURATION,
    ACT.CASH,
    COS.NAME,
    ACT.COMMENTS,
    ACT.TIP 
ORDER BY 
   --You can't use alias names in GROUP BY or ORDER BY clauses.
    COUNT(*)
```